# AWS Pinpoint : Active targetable endpoints is Nul

Tags: react-native, aws-pinpoint

I integrated AWS Amplify into my project react native. I use facebook Account Kit for connecting users. I'm having problems with aws pinpoint.

1. The analytics module works very well
2. the push notification module does not work very well:
3. the golds of tests to know to send a push notification according to the token FCM, I receive very well the message push notification.
4. In the dashboard impossible, you can not create segments or campaigns because "Active targetable endpoints is 0". What should I
   do please? I need your help.

Package

1. aws-amplify: 1.1.7
2. aws-amplify-react-native: 2.0.7
3. @ aws-amplify / pushnotification: 1.0.16
   **Sincerely**

Answer (score 0):

the endpoint should be automatically updated with the FCM token by Amplify when you opened the app. You can verify it by looking into the debug info.